# LookAt Implementation Misbehaviors

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, opengl-3, glulookat

I'm looking forward to implement a LookAt( forward, up ) method where:

```
Vector3 forward = eyePosition - targetPosition;
Vector3 up;
```

I've seen some implementations over the web, but analizing the code, I've found potencial misbehaviors...

I list them from easiest to hardest:

1) This won't work if UP is a zero vector.

2) This won't work if FORWARD is a zero vector.

3) This won't work if UP and FORWARD are parallels.

...

So.. How should this method correctly be implemented?

Here is a code example I've found.

```
/*
 *  gluLookAt.h
 *
 *  This is a modified version of the function of the same name from 
 *  the Mesa3D project ( http://mesa3d.org/ ), which is  licensed
 *  under the MIT license, which allows use, modification, and 
 *  redistribution
 *
 *  In order to work under OpenGL ES, all instances of GLdouble
 *  had to be changed to GLfloat, and all "d" function calls had
 *  to be changed to the "f" versions.
 *
 *  Original developer's comments have been left in place.
 *
 *  Out of respect for the original authors, this is licensed under
 *  the Mesa (MIT) license. Original license follows:
 *  
 *  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1999-2007  Brian Paul   All Rights Reserved.
 *  
 *  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
 *  copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
 *  to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
 *  the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
 *  and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 *  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *  
 *  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
 *  in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

 *  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
 *  OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 *  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
 *  BRIAN PAUL BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 *  AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 *  CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>

void gluLookAt(GLfloat eyex, GLfloat eyey, GLfloat eyez,
          GLfloat centerx, GLfloat centery, GLfloat centerz,
          GLfloat upx, GLfloat upy, GLfloat upz);



gluLookAt.m
/*
 *  gluLookAt.c
 */

#include "gluLookAt.h"

void gluLookAt(GLfloat eyex, GLfloat eyey, GLfloat eyez,
          GLfloat centerx, GLfloat centery, GLfloat centerz,
          GLfloat upx, GLfloat upy, GLfloat upz)
{
    GLfloat m[16];
    GLfloat x[3], y[3], z[3];
    GLfloat mag;

    /* Make rotation matrix */

    /* Z vector */
    z[0] = eyex - centerx;
    z[1] = eyey - centery;
    z[2] = eyez - centerz;
    mag = sqrt(z[0] * z[0] + z[1] * z[1] + z[2] * z[2]);
    if (mag) {          /* mpichler, 19950515 */
        z[0] /= mag;
        z[1] /= mag;
        z[2] /= mag;
    }

    /* Y vector */
    y[0] = upx;
    y[1] = upy;
    y[2] = upz;

    /* X vector = Y cross Z */
    x[0] = y[1] * z[2] - y[2] * z[1];
    x[1] = -y[0] * z[2] + y[2] * z[0];
    x[2] = y[0] * z[1] - y[1] * z[0];

    /* Recompute Y = Z cross X */
    y[0] = z[1] * x[2] - z[2] * x[1];
    y[1] = -z[0] * x[2] + z[2] * x[0];
    y[2] = z[0] * x[1] - z[1] * x[0];

    /* mpichler, 19950515 */
    /* cross product gives area of parallelogram, which is < 1.0 for
     * non-perpendicular unit-length vectors; so normalize x, y here
     */

    mag = sqrt(x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1] + x[2] * x[2]);
    if (mag) {
        x[0] /= mag;
        x[1] /= mag;
        x[2] /= mag;
    }

    mag = sqrt(y[0] * y[0] + y[1] * y[1] + y[2] * y[2]);
    if (mag) {
        y[0] /= mag;
        y[1] /= mag;
        y[2] /= mag;
    }

#define M(row,col)  m[col*4+row]
    M(0, 0) = x[0];
    M(0, 1) = x[1];
    M(0, 2) = x[2];
    M(0, 3) = 0.0;
    M(1, 0) = y[0];
    M(1, 1) = y[1];
    M(1, 2) = y[2];
    M(1, 3) = 0.0;
    M(2, 0) = z[0];
    M(2, 1) = z[1];
    M(2, 2) = z[2];
    M(2, 3) = 0.0;
    M(3, 0) = 0.0;
    M(3, 1) = 0.0;
    M(3, 2) = 0.0;
    M(3, 3) = 1.0;
#undef M
    glMultMatrixf(m);

    /* Translate Eye to Origin */
    glTranslatef(-eyex, -eyey, -eyez);

}
```

Comment: Depending on your philosophy of how functions should react to degenerate parameter values, this implementation is fine. Most of OpenGL behaves badly if you provide degenerate arguments. The burden of ensuring meaningful arguments is placed on the programmer. Your conditions 1-3 preclude a valid scene view, so bad behavior is at least consistent with the rest of OpenGL.  If you want a version of gluLookAt that checks its arguments, just write a wrapper for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I've just got to an idea to solve this problem. I haven't test it, not even code it yet, but I share the idea to discuss it, I appreciate your opinion!!

Pseudo code: (using column major matrix and right-handed coordinate system)

```
// transformation matrix (column major)
float matrix[16];

void crossProduct( const flaot a[3], const float b[3], float result[3] ) {
    result[0] = a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1];
    result[1] = -a[0] * b[2] + a[2] * b[0];
    result[2] = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
} 

void LookAt( float forward[3], float up[3] ) {
    // get forward length
    int length = sqrt( forward[0] * forward[0] + forward[1] * forward[1] + forward[2] * forward[2] );
    // if not zero, normalize it
    if ( length ) {
        forward[0] /= length;
        forward[1] /= length;
        forward[2] /= length;
    } else {
        // get last forward direction
        forward[0] = matrix[8];
        forward[1] = matrix[9];
        forward[2] = matrix[10];
    }

    // get up length
    length = sqrt( up[0] * up[0] + up[1] * up[1] + up[2] * up[2] );
    // if not zero, normalize it
    if ( length ) {
        up[0] /= length;
        up[1] /= length;
        up[2] /= length;
    } else {
        // get last up direction
        up[0] = matrix[4];
        up[1] = matrix[5];
        up[2] = matrix[6];
    }

    float left[3];
    crossProduct( up, forward, left);
    // if cross product is zero, forward and up are parallels. get last left direction
    if ( left[0]==0 && left[1]==0 && left[2]==0 ) {
        left[0] = matrix[0];
        left[1] = matrix[1];
        left[2] = matrix[2];
    }

    // recalculate orthogonal up
    crossProduct( forward, left, up );

    // update matrix values
    matrix[0] = left[0];
    matrix[1] = left[1];
    matrix[2] = left[2];
    matrix[3] = 0;
    matrix[4] = up[0];
    matrix[5] = up[1];
    matrix[6] = up[2];
    matrix[7] = 0;
    matrix[8] = forward[0];
    matrix[9] = forward[1];
    matrix[10] = forward[2];
    matrix[11] = 0;
    matrix[12] = 0;
    matrix[13] = 0;
    matrix[14] = 0;
    matrix[15] = 1;
}
```