# Adjusting glRotate, using dot product

Tags: c++, c, math, opengl, vector-graphics

Introducing:
I'm developing a little Tower defense game in opengl, currently I'm just despairing of a little problem....

I want the projectiles from the tower to aim with the head facing the unit. So my problem is more a mathmatical one but it belongs to opengl :)

I had the following idea; I could use a dot product to get an angle rotating around the x axis to get the head depending on the distance just straight down or flat to the ground and after that an additional angle to rotate around the y axis that the head of the arrow is everytime adjusted to the unit it's aiming on.

My code for the angle of rotation around the X axis (i called it m_fYNeigung because the height(Y) of the head changes by rotating around the x axis) looks like this:

```
plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_fYNeigung = 
RADIANS_TO_DEGREES (acos ((float)
        (
            (faTowerPosition[0]) * (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[0]) +
            (faTowerPosition[1] - 1) * (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[1]) +
            (faTowerPosition[2]) * (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[2])
        )
        /
        (
            fabs (faTowerPosition[0]) * fabs (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[0]) +
            fabs (faTowerPosition[1] - 1) * fabs (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[1]) +
            fabs (faTowerPosition[2]) * fabs (plocalTowerArray[(sizeMapIndexY * 12) + sizeMapIndexX].Projektils[byteProjectilIndex].m_faProDirectionVector[2])
        )
));
```

where faTowerPosition is the first vector, which is pointing down from the top of the tower (the arrow also starts at faTowerPosition[X/Y/Z]) the second vector for the dot product is m_faProDirectionVector which is a normalized direction vector describing the route of the arrow from the tower to the unit.

The Opengl Drawing part looks just as simple as this:

```
        for (sizeJ = 0; sizeJ < localTowerArray[sizeI].m_byteProjectilAmount; sizeJ++)
        {
            if (localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_bOnFlight == true)
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef (localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_faProPosition[0], localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_faProPosition[1], localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_faProPosition[2]);
                //glRotatef (360.0f - localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_fXNeigung, 0, 1, 0);
                glRotatef (localTowerArray[sizeI].Projektils[sizeJ].m_fYNeigung, 1, 0, 0);
                    DrawWaveFrontObject (m_pArrowProjektilObject);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
```

Just ignore the calculations I'm doing to the angle, I just did it to experiment with the acting of the arrows, i just noticed that it appears as would the arrow act different depending on the (i gotta say: the buildable map is scaled by x: -3.4 to 3.4 and z from 4 to -4) cords the tower was builded on -x/z,-z/x,z/x,-z/-x all these cases i guess are different and at least depending on the unit is running left or right side of the tower, the acting is also different.... so what i forgot to remind by using the dot product in this way?

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code that it's hard to answer this question. Why use size as a prefix for an index? What's with the German names? Why is there so much duplicate code? Why don't you use structs for points? Most importantly, why even post your code if you're asking a maths question? Anyways. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008303/lookat-implementation-misbehaviors .

Comment: size prefix, because they are of type size_t. the german names"s" ... the only german name is the var "neigung". I explained it. Its an angel and neigung means something like pitch. im not sure what u do mean with duplicate code.... i just wrote it this way to keep the form of the dot product, that its easier to get what im doing.... and what do u mean with structs for points? Im posting my code to explain my problem, to refer to a problem because i dont know whats causing my problem. At least... the link u posted has absolutly nothing to do with my problem, but thanks anyway:)

Comment: before downvoting, maybe tell me what "so much" is wrong with my code? the code it self is running without any problems.... its just the working of the dot product. Why it doesn't do what should be its behavior?!

Comment: Well, this is not codereview. Sorry if I sound harsh. The main problem is that your question is extremely long and unclear. Judging from Tomás' answer, if you really just wanted to convert a normal vector to Euler angles then you could (and should) have asked that in two sentences, without posting any code. You should most definitely use a function for that, which takes a normal vector, and returns Euler angles. You could maybe post that function if it doesn't work. But please don't post for loops, as they have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Yep Andreas, you'r right, but i didn't heard about Euler angles before. so i wasn't able to consider this. I solved the problem now on a different own way... i just used the trigonometry to get the angles. But "You should most definitely use a function for that, which takes a normal vector, and returns Euler angles. " exactly that was it what i wanted to do. Im sry that i cant keep my question in small sentences... ill try to do it next time better, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all, your code is very difficult to understand, so I'm guessing a lot to try to answer you. If I assume something wrong, my apologize for it.

I am assuming that you want to use the euler angle rotation to align correctly your projectiles. So, first you will do a X rotation and after that, a Y rotation.

To do a X rotation, your vectors, for the dot product, must be on an YZ plane and assuming that your projectile start at Z direction, your first vector is (0, 0, 1). The second vector, as you said, is a vector pointing to unit and could be expressed by (px, py, pz). You must project this vector to the plane YZ to get the second vector for your dot product, so this vector will be (0, py, pz)

Now, to calculate the dot product you apply the following formule

> x1.x2+y1.y2+z1.z2 = |p1|.|p2|.cos a, where |p1| and |p2| is the module of vector (its length)

In this example, the first vector is unitary, but the second not. So |p2| = sqrt(py^2 +pz^2). Thereafter:

> acos(a) = pz/sqrt(py^2 + pz^2)

This will give you the angle around X axis. Do the same calculation to achieve Y angle rotation

PS. After I wrote this answer, I noted that you use the function "fabs". I guess you want to find the module of you second vector, but fabs give you the absolute value of a escalar. To calculate a module of a vector (its length) you need to use the above formulae as cited.

Comment: im using fabs because i thought |x| is eq to sqrt (x^2) your explanation sounds pretty nice and ill remind your "how to ask" hint next time :) but it also appears to be the same im alrdy doing... well g2g now ill give it a try this night or tomorrow, maybe i just got a little mindtrap :D so ill let ya know and thanks anyway :)